# Component-wise double precision multiplication in Go

Tags: go, mathematics, physics

I'm working on porting the bullet3 physics engine to Go to learn more about physics simulations. I'm working through some of the convex hull computing code, and I've reached a component-wise, double precision multiplication class in the original C++ code. I'm not familiar with this type of low-level math, so I'm not sure if I've ported the intent of the method properly. [Here](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/src/Bullet3Geometry/b3ConvexHullComputer.cpp#L580) is the original method, which is a generic definition - I've looked through the rest of the bullet3 source and the generic method is only used on `Int128` and `Uint64` types, so my implementation is only for `Int128` with the appropriate conversions. I used the [go-num library by Blake Williams](https://github.com/shabbyrobe/go-num) for the `Int128` implementation.

```golang
func DMul128(a Int128, b Int128, low *Int128, high *Int128) {
    mul := func(a, b Uint64) *Int128 {
        x := Int128FromUint64(a).Mul(Int128FromUint64(b))
        return &x
    }

    low = mul(a.lo, b.lo)
    p01 := mul(a.lo, b.hi)
    p10 := mul(a.hi, b.lo)
    high = mul(a.hi, b.hi)
    p0110 := p01.lo + p10.lo

    *high = high.Add(Int128FromUint64(p01.hi)).
        Add(Int128FromUint64(p10.hi)).
        Add(Int128FromUint64(Int128FromUint64(p0110).hi))

    p0110 <<= 32
    *low = low.Add(Int128FromUint64(p0110))

    if low.LessThan(Int128FromUint64(p0110)) {
        *high = high.Add(Int128FromUint64(1))
    }
    return
}
```

Have I ported the intent of the method properly?

Comment: Have you written unit-tests?  A suitable set of inputs will help with confidence about correctness.

Comment: I have unit tested it for small numbers that I can hand verify, but I've never worked with this type of applied math so I'm not 100% sure how I should test it beyond adding numbers up.